# ACE Editor Apache Freemarker template require does not load

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

### Introduction

I want to implement the custom mode https://github.com/heygrady/ace-mode-freemarker for Freemarker templates (http://freemarker.org/).

I have created a file `mode-freemarker.js` inside my `src-noconflict/` folder. The file represents the code of this file: https://github.com/heygrady/ace-mode-freemarker/blob/master/freemarker.js . For non conflict source if have changed the `define()` line to

```
ace.define("ace/mode/freemarker", ["require", "exports", "module", "ace/lib/oop", "ace/mode/javascript"], function(require, exports, module) {
```

So, the whole file looks like:

```js
/* ***** BEGIN LICENSE BLOCK *****
 * Distributed under the BSD license:
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Ajax.org B.V.
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *     * Neither the name of Ajax.org B.V. nor the
 *       names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
 *       derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL AJAX.ORG B.V. BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 *
 * Contributor(s):
 * 
 *
 *
 * ***** END LICENSE BLOCK ***** */

/*
  THIS FILE WAS AUTOGENERATED BY mode.tmpl.js
*/

/* global ace*/
ace.define("ace/mode/freemarker", ["require", "exports", "module", "ace/lib/oop", "ace/mode/javascript"], function(require, exports, module) {
 "use strict";

 var oop = require("../lib/oop");
 var TextMode = require("./text").Mode;
 var JavaScriptMode = require("./javascript").Mode;
 var CssMode = require("./css").Mode;
 var Tokenizer = require("../tokenizer").Tokenizer;
 var FreeMarkerHighlightRules = require("./freemarker_highlight_rules").FreeMarkerHighlightRules;
 var MatchingBraceOutdent = require("./matching_brace_outdent").MatchingBraceOutdent;

 // TODO: pick appropriate fold mode
 var HtmlBehaviour = require("./behaviour/html").HtmlBehaviour;
 var HtmlFoldMode = require("./folding/html").FoldMode;

 var Mode = function() {
  // NOTE: borrowed from Html
  var highlighter = new FreeMarkerHighlightRules();
  this.$tokenizer = new Tokenizer(highlighter.getRules());
  this.$behaviour = new HtmlBehaviour();
  this.$outdent = new MatchingBraceOutdent();

  this.$embeds = highlighter.getEmbeds();
  this.createModeDelegates({
   "js-": JavaScriptMode,
   "css-": CssMode
    //      "freemarker-": FreeMarkerMode
  });

  this.foldingRules = new HtmlFoldMode();
 };
 oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

 (function() {
  // NOTE: borrowed from Liquid, doesn't seem to do anything
  this.toggleCommentLines = function(state, doc, startRow, endRow) {
   var outdent = true;
   var outentedRows = [];
   var re = /^(\s*)#/;

   for (var i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
    if (!re.test(doc.getLine(i))) {
     outdent = false;
     break;
    }
   }

   if (outdent) {
    var deleteRange = new Range(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (var i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
     var line = doc.getLine(i);
     var m = line.match(re);
     deleteRange.start.row = i;
     deleteRange.end.row = i;
     deleteRange.end.column = m[0].length;
     doc.replace(deleteRange, m[1]);
    }
   } else {
    doc.indentRows(startRow, endRow, "#");
   }
  };

  this.getNextLineIndent = function(state, line, tab) {
   var indent = this.$getIndent(line);

   var tokenizedLine = this.$tokenizer.getLineTokens(line, state);
   var tokens = tokenizedLine.tokens;
   var endState = tokenizedLine.state;

   if (tokens.length && tokens[tokens.length - 1].type == "comment") {
    return indent;
   }

   if (state == "start") {
    var match = line.match(/^.*[\{\(\[]\s*$/);
    if (match) {
     indent += tab;
    }
   }

   return indent;
  };

  this.checkOutdent = function(state, line, input) {
   return this.$outdent.checkOutdent(line, input);
  };

  this.autoOutdent = function(state, doc, row) {
   this.$outdent.autoOutdent(doc, row);
  };
 }).call(Mode.prototype);

 exports.Mode = Mode;
});
```

### Problem

But, when I do a `editor.setMode("ace/mode/freemarker");` I only get this error:

```
mode-freemarker.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mode' of undefined
    at mode-freemarker.js:46
```

That means, the require javascript mode can not be loaded in this line:

```
var JavaScriptMode = require("./javascript").Mode;
```

Why is this file mode-javascript not loaded over require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to also include [freemarker_highlight_rules](https://github.com/heygrady/ace-mode-freemarker/blob/master/freemarker_highlight_rules.js#L31) file and html mode from ace.

Comment: Yes, this is included. But, it stops on line 46 where the script tries to load the javascript mode.

Comment: which html mode did you include? html mode has javascript mode https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/mode-html.js#L698

Comment: I have only setMode("ace/mode/freemarker"); What do you mean with include? Must I define the ace/mode/javascript also in the mode-freemarker.js file?

Comment: yes either copy paste whole mode-html.js file in freemarker.js or load mode-html.js with script tag